# How to load the examples given by st on an IDB008V2 board?

Tags: stm32, keil, truestudio, bluenrg

I need to develop software on a bluenrg-2.
I use the IDB008V2 development board. I would like to use the chat example provided by ST: https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-bluenrg-dk.html

The compilation works correctly but it is impossible to load it into the board.
It restarts and the old program is still present.
In addition, the card is not detected by the stlinkv2 (via JTAG), I am forced to use the USB port.

- I tried all the other examples by getting the same problem.
- I used Keil and Truestudio, I get the same results.
- However when I create a new program (the basic one of Truestudio) it can be correctly uploaded to the board and works perfectly.
- I also tried to port the different source files used by ST's chat to a new project, but I quickly find myself with many dependencies problems such as undeclared variables, etc.

I don't know if it's a good idea to port the source files to a new project. It would be a good start if I could load the example program to the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes user forgot he enabled Simulation in the options.
For Keil MDK, please in Option | Debug , select "Use ST-Link Debugger" instead of "Use Simulator"

Besides, by default SWD shall be used. In the Target Com Port, please select "SW" instead of "JTAG".

Then please check: in Flash Download, the BlueNRG-2 On-chip Flash shall be present:
[image]

Please Add manually if it is not seen.